# Android - Can you mix types in a Custom Adapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter

For an Adapter, you would give it some type of collection of objects/types, like

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>;
myCustomAdapter adapter = new myCustomAdapter(this, myList);
```

What if you wanted to use multiple types of Objects in your adapter. So certain items in the adapter would be one object while other items would be different objects. How would you go about doing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have control over the code within `myCustomAdapter`? If so, you can create an interface that all of your objects will share, make your adapter generic and constrain the type parameter to that interface.

```
public interface IAdapterItem{
    //Whatever functionality is needed
}

public class MyCustomAdapter<T extends IAdapterItem> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{
    //Adapter implementation
}
```